# Definition of support of a continuous function

Tags: analysis, definition

Let $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set, $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ a continuous function. I have always defined the support of $f$ to be
$$\operatorname{supp}(f) := \overline{ \{ x \in \Omega \mid f(x) \neq 0 \} } $$
where the closure is taken with respect to the topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$. During a lecture the professor suggested that there should be a definition s.t. $f$ is defined on (or can be continuously extended to) $\operatorname{supp}(f)$, but didn’t remember the details.

We figured that there must be some requirements about the connectedness of $\Omega$ and the absence of holes (so that situations like $f(x):=\frac{1}{\left\lVert x \right\rVert}$ on $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$ can be avoided).
I also checked some books but they either give the definition I was used to (e.g. Rudin or Zuily) or just take the closure with respect to the topology of $\Omega$ (e.g. Hormander), but this last trick feels a bit like cheating, since in this way it is assured that $\operatorname{supp}(f) \subseteq \Omega$.

Is there any book where the support of a continuous function is defined differently or where the problem of extending $f$ to its own support is discussed?

Comment: What you need is a condition on $f$, not $\Omega$. What can go wrong with extending $f$ is that the limit of $f$ as you approach any boundary point of $\Omega$ may not converge. There is no condition you can put on $\Omega$ itself that guarantees this will not occur. Give many any open proper subset, and I can construct a continuous function that fails to converge at some boundary point. Such an $f$ cannot be continuously extended.

Comment: What your professor might have been thinking of is the case where $f$ is defined and continuous on $\overline\Omega$.